# how to send data from child frame to main frame using wxpython

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, subprocess

I am new to wxpython ,i wanted to know how we can send data from child frame to main frame in wxpython?

Here is brief discription about my prog:
  child frame has spinctrl and a button , when we click on the button mainframe should get those value which is used for furthur application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to send messages across frames like this, using Publisher from wx.lib.pubsub.  You `subscribe` to a message in the main frame, and then `sendMessage` from the child frame.

For an example and more info, see 
http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/